# Main process exited code=exited status=203/exec

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, wsgi

I followed a flask+uwsgi+nginx tutorial like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04). However it comes with error:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of myproject.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daem-reload' to reload units>
● myproject.service - uWSGI instance to serve myproject
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-05-05 18:26:18 AEST; 20min ago
 Main PID: 38304 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 05 18:26:18 ip-10-86-162-214.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve myproject。
May 05 18:26:18 ip-10-86-162-214.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: myproject.service: Main process exited code=exited status=203/exec
May 05 18:26:18 ip-10-86-162-214.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: myproject.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=rh
WorkingDirectory=/home/rh/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/rh/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/rh/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The "rh" is the user I used.